# Joomla for fully coded based website

Tags: joomla2.5

I am software based developer based on HTML,CSS,Javascript,C,C++,Java,PHP,MYSQL and SQL server.

I am building my own website based on above language.Which currently now in complete.

So,I will going to use own home based linux server.

My question is that,I heard about joomla.What it is? It use for security or design who just starter programmer who want create website Or it can also use for professional developer?
Can joomla can be used for  full own program based website?

If, yes! then how?

Also any other tools available for extra security for website for own based server?

Answer (score 2):

It's a content management system (cms) based on php. You can find out more information about joomla here: [about joomla](http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla.html)

In terms of security, I would say uppdating your joomla version as they are released, correct permissions and htaccess will be a start. Take a look at the security check list here: [security check list](http://docs.joomla.org/Category%3aSecurity_Checklist)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already read it before comment.Thanks for reply friend.I download some ebooks also. Take care.